# About groups of order $n=2^q\cdot3^r\cdot5^s\cdot7^t$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group with order $n=2^q\cdot3^r\cdot5^s\cdot7^t$, where the powers are non-negative integers.

We are looking for some conditions on $q,r,s,t$ and $G$ such that
$G$ has some elements of order $d$ with $d\geq 8$ or $d=6$.

For example, if at least two elements of $q,r,s,t$ are non-zero and $G$ is abelian, then the property is satisfied.

- Now, can somebody give some various conditions on the powers and/or $G$ for which such elements exist?

Comment: You can weaken the condition that $G$ be abelian to just assuming it is nilpotent (along with the assumption that two or more exponents are non-zero).

Comment: Thanks, Any other conditions, if $G$ is not nilpotent? , or some other  classes of such groups without the property (except that $p$-groups)?